# Jquery select only neighbor

Tags: jquery

I've got:

```
<div class="row even">
    <div class="more">more</div>
    <div class="body">Some additional text</div>
</div>
<div class="row odd">
    <div class="more">more</div>
    <div class="body">Anoteher text</div>
</div>
```

And I want to toggle div with "body" class when "more" div is clicked but only in their common row class.

```
$('.more').click(function() {
$('.body').toggle();
});
```

But it toggle all div with "body" class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.more').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.body').toggle();
});
```

Workig demo - http://jsfiddle.net/AsLWf/1/

Answer (score 2):

Use the [next](http://api.jquery.com/next/) function:

```
$('.more').click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings) traversal function with a selector:

```
$(this).siblings('.body').toggle();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using next() method:

```
$('.more').click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```